# If a marked flag is helpful, does this means the question will be closed?

Tags: discussion, flags

I've flagged a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476282/android-edittext-settext-not-working) on SO and the flag is marked as helpful.

[image]

I was assuming that a helpful flag on a question implies that it will be closed. But in this case the question in not closed. Will that question be closed. If not then what will happen to that question?

Comment: Keep using flags as close-vote proxies and don't be surprised when future flags aren't ever addressed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, "helpful" only means that the flag had (some) merit.

In the specific case, I suspect your flag was marked as "helpful" automatically when the question received a close vote after you flagged it.

Comment: will that question be closed or deleted in future because of my flag? What are (some) merits?

Comment: FYI, there is no close vote on the question

Comment: @Jaguar A flag is just a signal. There's no way to tell (for sure) if the question will be closed or deleted in the future. Since there are no close votes on the question, you can interpret "helpful" as: This didn't require a moderator to intervene, but it also wasn't a complete waste of time. Conversely, why are you flagging instead of voting to close?

Comment: @Yannis How can a 4k user flag as NARQ instead of closing?

Comment: I can vote for close, a maximum of 50 questions only, and unfortunately I finished all of them.

Comment: @Jaguar I have once used up the 50 close votes, but there is still no option to flag (it just redirects me to the close window, which tells me I have no votes left).

Comment: @Antony After your 50 close votes, you can still flag a post

Comment: @Antony: He used a custom flag. If you look at the flag message, it starts with a capital letter, whereas real close flags don't start with a capital letter.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn So can I assume that a moderator has marked the flag as helful only to motivate me?

Comment: @Jaguar: I didn't handle your flag, but in this case it means no action was needed. FYI, you should not be flagging questions with pseudo-close-votes just because you've run out of actual close votes. There is a reason why the site limits your close votes each day.

Comment: @Jaguar - if you've run out of close votes, stop and go and do something else.